# Changing java 7 to java 8 ubuntu openjdk not working

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have a project that runs on Jenkins using docker. At start the docker have java 7 installed by default which is necesary for the project to build. But after, the proyect build and is up, I need to install java 8 to run the e2e tests, selenium server needs java 8. So to install java 8 i use openjdk8 the following ways:

```
apt-get -y update
apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
echo 'Changing Java version, it should be 8'
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
echo "path"
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo "version java"
java -version
```

The problem is that when this runs it still outputs the java 7. Below output from the code above.

```
Changing Java version, it should be 8
path
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
version java
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Just for the record: why updating one container to use *another* container? Why not create two containers in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

you can do following:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac 1
```

and then by using following you can set the config to use which version:

```
update-alternative --config java
update-alternative --config javac
```

Comment: Unclear at which point I should add that command. I'm new to docker and jenkins.

Comment: you should run above commands on your terminal. Those are your java configs which are independent of your docker and jenkins.

Comment: I need the run the commands via script, since these run on a container.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that java8 home/bin is first in the path

```
update-java-alternatives --list | grep java-8
export JAVA_HOME= java 8 path here 
export PATH=$JAVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install -y java-common